# Size of smallest multiple $\sum \epsilon_i p^i$ of $n$ with digits $\epsilon_i\in \{0,1\}$ for $p$ a prime

Tags: nt.number-theory

Any natural number $n$ coprime with a prime number $p$ is a divisor of 
$M=1+p+p^2+\dots+P^{N-1}$ where $N\leq \varphi((p-1)n)$ is the order of
$p$ in $\left(\mathbb Z/((p-1)n)\mathbb Z\right)^*$.

The integer $M$ is minimal with this property and is of course in general exponentially larger than $n$.

(Added correction: The minimal integer M is in fact given by
$N=\varphi(n)$ for $n$ coprime to $p-1$. Thanks to Seva for this remark.)

Can this exponential bound be improved to a polynomial one when allowing 
digits in $\{0,1\}$? Otherwise stated, given a prime number $p$, does there
exist a constant $\alpha=\alpha(p)$ such that every natural integer $n$
has a non-zero multiple $M=dn$ with $M\leq n^\alpha$ a sum of distinct powers of $p$?

(The result is of course trivially true for $p=2$.)

There are of course many related questions:

If yes, what is asymptotically the best constant $\alpha$ (i.e. we want $M\leq n^{\alpha(1+\epsilon)}$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and for all but a finite number of $n$)?

How does $\alpha$ grow with $p$? (A trivial lower bound comes from a counting argument.)

Etc.

Added after a comment of Douglas Zare: The question makes of course perfectly sense for
non-prime $p\geq 2$.

Comment: Coincidentally, I just answered a different but related question here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/272517/dynamic-programming-problem-to-find-smallest-integer-number-x-which-contains

Comment: The question makeds however no much sense for non-prime $p$, except by removing an obvious set of "bad" integers from $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Which part doesn't make sense for non-prime $p$?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. There are no problems for $p$ non-prime with my question.

Comment: The question would have a simple answer if you were allowing $-1$ as a coefficient. In this case, for $k\ge\log_2n$, at least two of the sums $\epsilon_0+\epsilon_1p+\dotsb+\epsilon_kp^k$ are congruent modulo $n$, and their difference is an algebraic sum of powers of $p$, divisible by $n$. Thus, you can take $\alpha=\log_2 p$ in this case.

Comment: Something to try: start with sum p^i for i from log n on up, and see if you can add log n many small powers to get a large multiple of n.  Then subtract from M.

Comment: Perhaps, a more appealing form of this question is this: for co-prime integer $p,n>1$, what is the smallest multiple of $n$ written to the base $p$ with the digits $0$ and $1$ only?

Comment: Seva, you are of course right concerning the factor $(p-1)$. The only reason for the necessity of the factor $p-1$ is thus the fact that my keyboard is faster than my brain. By the way, your suggestion of using digits in $\{0,\pm 1\}$ leads to the (proven) existence of asymptotically optimal exponents in this case.

Comment: In fact, it seems to me now that I was wrong. The congruence $p^N\equiv1\pmod n$ does not automatically imply $n\mid1+p+\dotsb+p^{N-1}$ as we do not assume $(n,p-1)=1$.

Comment: I hope the question is now converging to something correct. Thank you Seva for your remarks.

Answer (score 1):

While $M=n^{O_p(1)}$ can be tricky (or out of reach), the following argument shows that $M\le p^{(2+o(1))\sqrt{dn}}$ with $d=\gcd(p-1,n)$; thus, $M<\exp(O(\sqrt n))$ in the regime where $p$ is fixed and $n$ grows.

Recall that the *critical number* of a finite abelian group $G$ is defined to be the smallest positive integer $k=k(G)$ such that for any $k$-element subset $A\subset G\setminus\{0\}$, every element of $G$ is representable as a non-empty sum of pairwise distinct elements of $A$. It is known that if $G$ is cyclic, then its critical number is at most $(2+o(1))\sqrt{|G|}$; see, for instance the paper by Hamidoune, Llado, and Serra "[On Complete Subsets of the Cyclic Group](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S009731650800006X/1-s2.0-S009731650800006X-main.pdf?_tid=b1682b34-eca9-11e4-aff0-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1430117609_c121a6bfeff2b580151273531596e6e4)".

Let now $k$ being the critical number of the group ${\mathbb Z}/dn{\mathbb Z}$, so that $k\le(2+o(1))\sqrt{dn}$. If the order of $p$ in this group does not exceed $k-1$, then we have $p^s\equiv 1\pmod{dn}$ with some $s\le k-1$, implying $n\mid 1+p+\dotsb+p^{s-1}$; thus, we can set $M:=1+p+\dotsb+p^{s-1}$. Otherwise, consider the set $A:=\{1,p,p^2,\ldots,p^{k-1}\}$. By the definition of a critical number, one can select several elements from this set so that their sum is divisible by $dn$, and we define $M$ to be the sum of these numbers.

---

One further observation is that if $p\equiv 1\pmod n$, then in order for a sum of powers of $p$ to be divisible by $n$, one needs to have at least $n$ such powers; hence, $M>p^{n-1}$ in this case. This does not, of course, show that $M<n^{O(1)}$ fails to hold, as the assumption $p\equiv 1\pmod n$ is incompatible with the regime where $p$ is fixed and $n$ grows.